# Bootstrap text flows outside card

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble with a Bootstrap card, the text flows outside of the card box. The code which I have:

```
<div class="card">
     <div class="card-text">
        <div class="card-block">
          {!! $product->description  !!}
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have added `word-wrap: break-word !important;` to the card class but this isn't helping. Could someone help me fix my problem and keep my text within the card?

HTML OUTPUT:

```
<div class="card">
                        <div class="card-text">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <ul><li style="background: none 0px 0px / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box transparent; border: 0px none rgb(26, 26, 24); color: rgb(26, 26, 24); font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; height: 20px; left: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; outline-style: none; outline-width: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 16px; position: relative; top: auto; transform: none; vertical-align: baseline; width: 653.42px;">White: 170 g/m², kleur: 180 g/m²</li><li style="background: none 0px 0px / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box transparent; border: 0px none rgb(26, 26, 24); color: rgb(26, 26, 24); font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; height: 20px; left: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; outline-style: none; outline-width: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 16px; position: relative; top: auto; transform: none; vertical-align: baseline; width: 653.42px;">100% katoen</li><li style="background: none 0px 0px / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box transparent; border: 0px none rgb(26, 26, 24); color: rgb(26, 26, 24); font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; height: 20px; left: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; outline-style: none; outline-width: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 16px; position: relative; top: auto; transform: none; vertical-align: baseline; width: 653.42px;">Gevormde zijnaden met zijsplitjes voor een vrouwlijke pasvorm</li><li style="background: none 0px 0px / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box transparent; border: 0px none rgb(26, 26, 24); color: rgb(26, 26, 24); font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; height: 20px; left: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; outline-style: none; outline-width: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 16px; position: relative; top: auto; transform: none; vertical-align: baseline; width: 653.42px;">Smalle knoopsluiting met gelijkgekleurde knopen</li><li style="background: none 0px 0px / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box transparent; border: 0px none rgb(26, 26, 24); color: rgb(26, 26, 24); font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; height: 20px; left: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; outline-style: none; outline-width: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 16px; position: relative; top: auto; transform: none; vertical-align: baseline; width: 653.42px;">1x1 ribgebreide manchetten</li></ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML output (not the Blade template)?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards edited!

Comment: Thanks! It’s possible the `width: 653.42px;` is overwriting any containtment of the box – is it possible to remove that?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards yes removing that in the page works! now i have to find where this crazy style attribute is coming from..

Comment: Ah great, sounds like a wysiwyg thing – good luck!

Answer (score 0):

making the height:auto can resolve your issue.

Comment: no it will not :} the problem is she set width more than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

The explicit `width: 653.42px;` the `style` attribute will overwrite any CSS properties defined by Bootstrap.